# PHPunit different bootstrap for all testsuites

Tags: php, phpunit

```
<phpunit backupGlobals="false" colors="true">
    <testsuite name="app1" >
        <directory>./app1</directory>
    </testsuite>
    <testsuite name="app1" >
        <directory>./app2</directory>
    </testsuite>
</phpunit>
```

How can i make first and second testsuite load different bootstraps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.

PHPUnit only allows you to specify one bootstrap file and you need to set up everything so that each test case of each testsuite could potentially be executed and PHPUnit has no how of running "setup" code for each testsuite from a bootstrap xml file.

When using the, with phpunit 3.6 discouraged, `TestSuite` classes you could do it in those but my suggestion would be to just run all your generic bootstrap code in your bootstrap.php and should you need special setup for tests in app1 and in app2 to have a `App1_TestCase` you inherit from.

Should `App1` really be a whole application I'd suggest having two separate projects with their own tests and setup code and not trying to run them in one phpunit run.

Answer (score 28):

What I did is to have a Listener.

**phpunit.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit bootstrap="./phpunit_bootstrap.php"
     backupGlobals="false"
     backupStaticAttributes="false"
     verbose="true"
     colors="true"
     convertErrorsToExceptions="true"
     convertNoticesToExceptions="true"
     convertWarningsToExceptions="true"
     processIsolation="false"
     stopOnFailure="false"
     syntaxCheck="true">
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="unit">
            <directory>./unit/</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="integration">
            <directory>./integration/</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <listeners>
        <listener class="tests\base\TestListener" file="./base/TestListener.php"></listener>
    </listeners>
</phpunit>
```

Then **TestListener.php**

```
class TestListener extends \PHPUnit_Framework_BaseTestListener
{
    public function startTestSuite(PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite $suite)
    {
        if (strpos($suite->getName(),"integration") !== false ) {
            // Bootstrap integration tests
        } else {
            // Bootstrap unit tests
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this one, any idea on how to do it in PHPUnit 8 with extensions ? `PHPUnit\Runner\BeforeFirstTestHook`

Comment: This is 'the' way to go for running single tests in PHPStorm. in the `phpunit_bootstrap.php` is only a call to the autoloader, the specific bootstrap is managed by `TestListener`. Mind though, the `$suite->getName()` points to the dir of the test in case you run a single test through PHPStorm. So you'll need to check for a dir name to load the correct testsuite bootstrap.

Comment: This is not available in PHPUnit > 10.

Answer (score 20):

You can create two different bootstrap file and two different configuration xml files

**app1.xml**

```
<phpunit bootstrap="app1BootstrapFile.php" colors="true">
    <testsuite name="app1" >
        <directory>./app1</directory>
    </testsuite>
</phpunit>
```

**app2.xml**

```
<phpunit bootstrap="app2BootstrapFile.php" backupGlobals="false" colors="true">
    <testsuite name="app2" >
        <directory>./app2</directory>
    </testsuite>
</phpunit>
```

To run:

```
$phpunit --configuration app1.xml app1/
$phpunit --configuration app2.xml app2/
```

If you run one lot of test more that the other (say app1), name the xml phpunit.xml and you can just run

```
$phpunit app1/
$phpunit --configuration app2.xml app2/
```

I do this with unit/integration tests.

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea because to have 10 different bootstrap files you'll need, based on your solution, to create 10 phpunitblabla.xml files